# Что за предложение "Хорошая идея"?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Минэкономразвития думает о смягчении визового режима для иностранных туристов. Хорошая идея.

Что за предложение "Хорошая идея"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минэкономразвития думает о смягчении визового режима для иностранных туристов. **Хорошая идея.**

**Неполное предложение** с пропущенным подлежащим, которое восстанавливается из предыдущего текста: (Это) хорошая идея.